# How can I prevent a community user from creating an account?

Tags: community, administration

I am going through the community user setup and I found that the standard profile has access to read, edit and create accounts.

So I proceeded to edit the profile, but I am not able to take away the permissions. I want the user to have access to read the account, but I don't want the user to create or edit the account.

*In this particular org, we have used a profile for issuing permissions to community users.*

I have highlighted the license applied on this org.

This is the [help documentation link](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US#users_license_types_communities) I have found.

[image: Access Permissions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this.

One method is via use of Permissions Sets. These have not been implemented in this particular org.

The other method is clone the customer community plus profile and create another profile. In this newly created profile, take away the permissions for Create and Edit from the objects.

Now the community user should not be able to create an account.